# Facebook Sdk 3.5 send message to friend

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have read many posts about sending private message to a friend using facebook sdk but the some post are old and since facebook api has changed a lot since then and other provide javascript solution. I am using facebook sdk 3.5 and i wanna know does facebook allow sending a private message to a friend or not , if yes how ?
Can we use **send dialog** because on send dialog docs page(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)

there is a line saying **If you are using one of our iOS or Android SDKs to invoke the dialog, this is automatically specified and chooses an appropriate display type for the device.**

Can anyone plz tell me a proper way of sending message to a friend if its possible using Facebook sdk 3.5 for android

Comment: Hello. Did you managed to get it worked with sdk 3.5 ? If yes, could you please provide an example ? Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Unfortunately sending private message is not allowed through mobile sdk